# My Maui app is displaying Images in different locations based on the device language

Tags: c#, android, localization, maui

When my device is in english the UI objects are where I want to be but in some languages the row and col values gets switched up from left to right.. I would like to know how I can set the UI to be only in english. Its an Maui .net  android app.

here is an example -
[image]
[image]

Thanks for helping, this is really important!!

I have seen people talking about CultureInfo anf CurrentUICulture but it didnt work for me, maybe I didnt change it correctly or added it to the wrong place, if so I would love to know how and where exactly to use it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a [RTL case](https://medium.com/android-news/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2)

try to add `android:supportsRtl="false"` to `<application>` tag in your manifest

Comment: Yes!! I fixed it :DDD Can't tell you how grateful I am, thank you so much!